# Generate Bech32 addresses to receive customer funds

Tags: wallet, segregated-witness, address-generation

I would like to use Segwit addresses however I seem to be finding mixed information on compatibility. As I currently understand it, older clients will not be able to send to a Bech32 address.
Is this the case?

Per this development guide: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/
It sounds as if I should be creating P2SH-P2WPKH addresses for accepting deposits.

Answer (score 1):

> As I currently understand it, older clients will not be able to send to a Bech32 address. Is this the case?

Yes. Bech32 addresses are a completely new address type and format. Because it is new, many clients currently do not have Bech32 support implemented or have not yet released a version supporting it.

> It sounds as if I should be creating P2SH-P2WPKH addresses for accepting deposits.

Yes. For maximum compatibility, you should use P2SH-P2WPKH. Later you can transition to using Bech32 once more wallets implement support for Bech32 and it becomes widespread.